# Add field from query data to an Eloquent model without using an Attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to add a field to an Eloquent model instance. This field data comes from a query, not a constant or a value.

Yes, it could be done adding a field to $appends and adding an Attribute, but the problem with this approach is that it's not really added to the object as a field but as something like a function call, which makes that every time it's accessed it causes a query to the database, which if the data won't change will be time consuming needlessly.

In this case I could create a PDO and populate it, but I wonder if this could be done with Eloquent's ways.

I tried adding a Scope or something within the boot method, but nothing that worked.

I have searched but haven't found anything, so here I am asking if could it be done with a Scope, or the boot method or in any other Laravel/Eloquent way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So you say `I want to add a field to an Eloquent model instance` and then you note `it's not really added to the object` .... so make up your mind? Was this behaviour observed using the `$appends` field for a `Model`? It would be nice to see some small `this-is-how-i-would-like-it-to-work` example so we all the get the idea.

Comment: Tell us more about the query. Normally you can use relations in Eloquent or add extra attributes with getMyVarAttribute method.

Comment: @dbf I edited the question, but basically I wanted a field, at most a getter which retrieves a value, not a function which queries the database to return the same value every call as database values won't change. I don't get the make up my mind part though as I wasn't saying anything contradictory, as I was talking about the $appends approach.

Comment: @John Yes, true. I wasn't really clear on what my problem with your explanation was. All table fields a model refers to are based on the models `protected $attributes` property. I think it's the part you wrote `$appends and adding an Attribute`, so to my understanding, here you said you add something to `$appends` and added an `Attribute`.  Maybe that wasn't the case ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to make some things clear here. Using accessors on a model is something like computed fields, where you are able to call an attribute on a model that doesn't map to a field in the table, something like:

===

**A note on Laravel 9 documentation**

To make things more clearly, this was the only way to [use accessors with a model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) prior to Laravel 9. Since the release of Laravel 9, this approach isn't mentioned anymore in the documentation and the use of `Attribute` [is introduced](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#eloquent-accessors-and-mutators).

```
class User extends Model {
    protected function firstName(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => ucfirst($value),
        );
    }
}

// will search for a method called `firstName` and then `getFirstNameAttribute`.
User::find(1)->first_name;
```

To my opinion, this isn't making any improvement at all. This just narrows the models scope for using function names where it will accidentally hit a magic method call unwillingly due to all the magicness happening in Eloquents models already.

===

```
class User extends Model {

  function getMyFieldAttribute() {
    return "user {$this->id} computed value"  
  }

}

// will result in 'user 1 computed value'
echo User::find(1)->my_field;
```

The `$appends` attribute is used to append any none existing field from the table or relation to a processed output like JSON using `User::toJson()` or `User::toArray()`. You can also use the `$appends` field to save the state of any accessor field you define. Now you can use the combination of the two and if you would like to use a query to fill the attribute but this query should be executed once, just check if the attribute exists and if so, skip it.

```
class User extends Model {
    
  protected $appends = ['my_field'];

  // using $appends
  function getMyFieldAttribute() {
    if(!isset($this->attributes['my_field'])) {
      // perform a query, setting the time as an example
      $this->attributes['my_field'] = now();
    }

    return $this->attributes['my_field'];
  }
  
}

$User = User::find(1);
$index = 0;
while($index < 5) {
  // this query will be executed once
  echo "{$User->my_field}\n";
  $index++;
  // in this example you will see 5 times the same timestamp.
  sleep(1);
}
```

As [**yhiamdan**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75098940/1653305) pointed out in his answer, the getter method `getMyFieldAttribute` first parameter will be filled with the computed attributes value if set. On first call this value will be `null`, on any subsequent call it will be filled with the computed value if set with `setAttribute` or `$this->attributes`.

```
class User extends Model {

  public function getMyFieldAttribute($value) {
    if(!$value) {
      $value = now()
      $this->setAttribute('my_field', $value);
      // or the same with
      // $this->attributes['my_field'] = $value;
    }
    
    return $value;
  }

}
```

You cannot mix eloquents attributes with a defined property on the class `User`, this will never reach the magic methods `__get` or `__set` used to magically call the functions `getMyFieldAttribute` or `setMyFieldAttribute`.

```
class User extends Model {
  
  public $my_field = 'overwrite';

  public function getMyFieldAttribute() {
    return 'this will never be reached'
  }  

}

echo User::find(1)->my_field; // will output 'overwrite'
```

Just remind yourself that this is only the getter method of an accessor field. So the attribute `my_field` should have a `getMyFieldAttribute` and `setMyFieldAttribute` function. In the above setup, the `getMyFieldAttribute` is used as both where the value is variable and static when assigned.

Comment: Thanks. I missed I could access attributes with $this->attributes[x], so as for the case I was searching this for the values retrieved won't change, so this works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it could be done adding a field to $appends and adding an Attribute, but the problem with this approach is that it's not really added to the object but something like a function call, and every time it's accessed it causes a query to the database.**

Yes whenever you have an attribute defined on a model and you try to access it, the accessor function will be called every time. Its your job to decide whether to query the database or return the original result during the first query.

Lets say you have an attribute **fullname** on a user model and for some reasons computing the fullname is expensive and you do not want to recompute everytime the the attribute is accessed, you can set the result after the initial computation to your model's attributes using **$this->setAttribute("fullname",$result)**. This way, whenever you try to access the attribute, laravel will pass the value you assigned/set to the attribute to the accessor function, and you can check and decide whether to recompute or simply return the previous result.

This is an example

```
    public function getFullnameAttribute($val){
    if($val){
      return $val;
    }
    $fullname = //expensive computation;
    $this->setAttribute("fullname",$fullname);
    return $fullname;
    }
```

However what you need to consider is situations where the fullname attribute could be stale.

For instance when you retrieve a user model, you retrieve the **fullname** for the first time, then you change eg. the **firstname** attribute and then you try to retrieve the **fullname** attribute again, you will get the original fullname even if its dependent of the **firstname** attribute.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `getFullnameAttribute($val)` will only work in your example if there is a field called `fullname` in the table. If there is nothing to relate in the table, `$val` remains always `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my case the solution proposed by dbf works better for me.

Comment: @dbf can you confirm that with a test?, I did test that using laravel 9.39 and it works, could it be that there have been some changes?.

Comment: @yhiamdan yes, just use any none existing field, like so `public function getThiswillneverexistAttribute($value) { var_dump($value); return ''; }` and call any model with this function `Model::find(1)->thiswillneverexist;` will tell you `$value` is `null`. The `$value` argument is only filled if that field exists on the models table. In your case, `fullname` does probably exist in your user table. That is the reason why it contains a value.

Comment: @dbf oh yes, I understand what you mean, I am aware that is right, but it will exist after you explicitly set the attribute to the model using $this->setAttribute() function or some other means. If you don't set it then of course it will always be null.

Comment: @yhiamdan You are so right, it seems that computed attributes already set with `setAttribute` or `$this->attributes` get passed as an argument on subsequent calls. This is so pointless and quit frankly wrong, but yes it works like you described.

Comment: Added your approach in my answer .